# Migrate old deprecated methods in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to migrate `elasticsearch:5.6.15` to `elasticsearch:7.17.18`. I have the following issues:

```
TransportClient client;
DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder deleteRequestBuilder = DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client);
deleteRequestBuilder.source().setIndices(index);
```

Error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'newRequestBuilder' in 'DeleteByQueryAction'
```

Second issues is:

```
Retry retryRequest = Retry.on(Exception.class)
```

Error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'on' in 'Retry'
```

Third issue:

```
Map<String, Object> indexMapping;
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(index);
request.source(indexMapping);

Required type: XContentBuilder
Provided:Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>
```

Do you know how I can migrate the code accordingly?

P.S I created this test project to show migration issues:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/elasticsearch_migration_poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/portal/account/platform/service/WebhookPlatformClient.java

Please clone it and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch has already deprecated `Java REST Client` in favor of [Java API Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html). So you should migrate to *Java API Client*.

For your code, you can use the following code update for the issues.

1. Use a constructor instead of `newRequestBuilder`

```
DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder delete = new DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(client, DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE);
```

2. Use constructor instead of `Retry.on`

```
BackoffPolicy backoff = BackoffPolicy.exponentialBackoff(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(firstRetryWaitTimeInMillis), noOfRetries);
Retry retryBulkRequest = new Retry(backoff, client.threadPool());
BulkResponse response = retryBulkRequest.withBackoff(
            (bulkReq, bulkResponseActionListener) -> client.bulk(bulkReq, bulkResponseActionListener),
            bulkRequest.request()).actionGet();
BulkResponseDto responseDto = new BulkResponseDto();
responseDto.setTimeTakenInMilli(response.getIngestTookInMillis());
```

3. Pass `DeprecationHandler` as the second argument.

```
request.source(indexMapping, DeprecationHandler.IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS);
```

The above changes will solve the compilation issues. You can look for a migration guide or Elasticsearch Github for changes in different versions.